Scalikejdbc batch API
I am using Scalikejdbc batch APi to do insert operations for 20K rows. Unfortunately, I need to pass in table and column information also dynamically. So, below is my local tx code:
DB localTx {
        implicit session =>
        val batchParams: Seq[Seq[Any]] = data
        val columnNameString = columnNames.mkString(",")
        val parameterString = columnNames.map(x => "?").mkString(",")

        val queryInternals = SQLSyntax.createUnsafely(s"insert into $tableName ($columnNameString) values ($parameterString)")

        sql"$queryInternals".batch(batchParams: _*).apply()
      }

However, I am seeing in the logs, that it does insert statement 20K times..
What am I doing incorrect?

I'm not sure to understand the question: you were expecting a single INSERT statement with 20k rows and instead you've got 20k statements with one row each? If yes, does it really matter? Real question as I'm not sure it has a significant impact for performance as long as you're in a single connection/transaction.

ok. I always thought that single INSERT statement with 20K rows was always better (as Java/Scala does some preparing of the statement and uses that) as opposed to 20K INSERT INTO.. VALUES statement where for every statement Java needs to do the prep work. It is for sure single connection/transaction
